# ReactJS output html from prop loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have:

```
render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <col width="30"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="240"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>WETA</th>
                    <th>CETA</th>
                    <th>Chase</th>
                    <th>Tracking</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <col width="30"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="240"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                {this.props.rows.forEach((row) => {
                        <tr>
                            <td>{row.id}</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                )}
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>JC Electronics</td>
                    <td>24/06/2016</td>
                    <td>26/06/2016</td>
                    <td>27/06/2016</td>
                    <td>25/06/2016</td>
                    <td>S</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
```

But nothing comes out of that loop, this is the first time I have tried this so I will be doing something wrong, but what is it?

---

I seem to have done it by doing:

```
 render() {
        var rowData = this.props.rows.map((row) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <table className="table table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <col width="30"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="240"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>WETA</th>
                    <th>CETA</th>
                    <th>Chase</th>
                    <th>Tracking</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <col width="30"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="240"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                {rowData}
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>JC Electronics</td>
                    <td>24/06/2016</td>
                    <td>26/06/2016</td>
                    <td>27/06/2016</td>
                    <td>25/06/2016</td>
                    <td>S</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You want to use `map`, not `forEach`

Comment: @Bergi Still I get no output.

Comment: Are you sure that in your props.rows there is something? Try to insert before the return a "console.log(this.props.rows)" to see what rows contains

Comment: Please see my edit, it works but is it the proper way to do it?

Comment: React is likely now giving you a warning that you need to add a unique key to each element being mapped. See the docs about [dynamic children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

Comment: What is the actual question? You should use `map()` as @Bergi said and you need to return a value from the callback, which your original version didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. But you probably also want to render each `<td>` like how the row is rendered.

```
_renderRow(row, index) {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td key="0"></td>
      <td key="1">{row.qty}</td>
      <td key="2">{row.supplier}</td>
      <td key="3">{row.weta}</td>
      <td key="4">{row.ceta}</td>
      <td key="5">{row.chase}</td>
      <td key="6">{row.tracking}</td>
      <td key="7">{row.status}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>QTY</th>
          <th>Supplier</th>
          <th>WETA</th>
          <th>CETA</th>
          <th>Chase</th>
          <th>Tracking</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.props.rows.map((row, index) => this._renderRow(row, index))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```